# Нужна ли запятая перед тире после перечисления?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, однородные-члены, перечисление

> Он приподнял голову и обнаружил, что лежит на грязной косе у спокойной, мутной реки, окружённый группой аргониан с похожими узкими мордами и **чешуёй всех цветов радуги: ярко-зелёной и пурпурной, голубой и оранжевой(,) – красивой, как драгоценные камни**.

Аргониане - раса полуящеров-полулюдей из одной фэнтезийной вселенной. Нужна ли запятая в указанном месте?

На мой взгляд, если мы хотим отнести фразу после тире к "чешуёй всех цветов радуги", то запятая нужна, поскольку мы будем иметь определение, стоящее после определяемого слова ("чешуёй всех цветов радуги, красивой, как драгоценные камни"). Eсли фразу после тире мы хотим отнести к перечислению, то запятая не нужна. Но я не уверен, возможно ли такое отнесение и чем тогда фраза после тире будет по отношению к перечислению.

Comment: Мне не понравилась концовка, а начало ничего. "Он приподнял голову и обнаружил, что лежит на грязной косе у спокойной, мутной реки; окружённый группой аргониан, с похожими узкими мордами и чешуёй всех цветов радуги (ярко-зелёной и пурпурной, голубой и оранжевой); которую, поначалу ликуя, он перепутал с россыпью драгоценных камней, и даже успел размечаться, как лихо прокутит в столице внезапно свалившееся на голову сокровище!

Comment: Есть логическая ошибка. Если все цвета радуги, то надо все и назвать. Иначе надо "среди которых". Или "различных цветов радуги". А так получается, что у радуги всего четыре цвета. К тому же у радуги нет ярко-зелёного.

Comment: "Но все, кто видел, настоящую радугу, знают, что границы между цветами условны, один цвет плавно переходит в другой, и потому их количество может быть любым" ("Коммерсантъ").

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Здесь надо гуглить понятие "цвета радуги". То есть какие цвета считаются цветами радуги. Это семь цветов. Никак не четыре.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Ох уж это "писатели никогда не ошибаются"! Да постоянно ошибаются!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**А.** *Он приподнял голову и обнаружил, что лежит на грязной косе у спокойной, мутной реки, окружённый группой аргониан с похожими узкими мордами и **чешуёй всех цветов радуги:** ярко-зелёной и пурпурной, голубой и оранжевой, — красивой, как драгоценные камни.*

Нужна. Мне кажется, что здесь прекрасно подходят вот эти рекомендации Розенталя:

> **2.** Необходимость постановки тире в качестве дополнительного знака препинания определяется контекстом. Ср.:
> *На столе были разложены всевозможные предметы: книги, письменные принадлежности, географические карты, ящик, назначения которого никто не знал* — придаточная часть сложноподчиненного предложения относится к последнему однородному члену и тем самым включается в перечисление, а потому никакого дополнительного знака препинания не требуется;
> *На столе были разложены всевозможные предметы: книги, письменные принадлежности, географические карты, — которыми хозяин, по-видимому, давно не пользовался* — тире необходимо, чтобы показать, что придаточная часть относится ко всем однородным членам, точнее, к обобщающему слову.

Однородные определения (ярко-зелёной и пурпурной, голубой и оранжевой) относятся к выделенному обобщающему сочетанию — ставим двоеточие.
После них ставим запятую и тире, чтобы показать, что однородны согласованное и несогласованное определения (чешуёй (какой?) всех цветов радуги, красивой).

**Б.** *Он приподнял голову и обнаружил, что лежит на грязной косе у спокойной, мутной реки, окружённый группой аргониан с похожими узкими мордами и чешуёй всех цветов радуги **— ярко-зелёной и пурпурной, голубой и оранжевой, —** красивой, как драгоценные камни.*

Да, выделение с помощью парного тире тоже возможно (см. [Обобщающие слова при однородных членах предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103), п. 10), но в этом случае запятая ставится **только одна** (после последнего однородного определения — "оранжевой"; после "радуги" не ставится, потому что никакой оборот перед первым тире не закрывается) — то есть оформляется **по правилам вставки**.

[Сочетания знаков препинания. Запятая и тире](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=176#pp176)

Comment: @athlonusm О цитировании. Текст: *Он приподнял голову, **чтобы поглядеть, кто были эти "мы",** и обнаружил, что лежит на грязной косе...* Правильное оформление цитаты при пропуске должно быть таким (с многоточием): *Он приподнял **голову...** и обнаружил, что лежит на грязной косе...* (https://www.elderscrolls.net/skyrim/books/oblivionbooks/bk_argonianaccount.php?iframe=true&width=570&height=95%, Книга четвертая)

Answer (score 1):

...в художественном тексте не обязательно точное логическое соответствие формальным выражениям, но этот момент можно обработать, например перечислить более редкие оттенки, в классическую радугу не входящие, может похожие на камни - бирюза и амарант, лазурь и померанцово-красный..; которую... То есть уровень описания можно доработать и сделать эпитеты более сочными, потому что слова "красивая, как.." и похожие звучат как банальщина и по вкусу напоминают вчерашний фастфуд.

Но мне нравится сочетание блоков фраз.

И текст можно улучшать, даже если это перевод, тем более, если это перевод. Так как задача художественного текста вовлечь читателя в атмосферу, передать настроение, а это можно сделать, только уйдя от банальности. Если уйти от банальности звучания, то необычной можно сделать даже повседневность, если использовать штампы, то любые фэнтезийный или фантастический миры будут выглядеть плоско, но не как Плоский мир, а как коровья лепёшка.

Запятая перед тире, конечно, важный момент, но намного важнее, чтобы текст получился именно тот, потому что это не школа. В школе грамотно то, что правильно, а в искусстве грамотно то, что необычно но точно так. Запятые, формы слов, стилистика и прочее для художника - это средство достижения выразительности, инструменты языка, а вовсе не цель, расставить все запятые = получить пятёрку. Звучание слов, ритмика также. Текст должен быть свежим, сочным и мелодичным, только тогда он может считаться грамотным, а вовсе не когда стоит запятая перед тире.

Если не знаешь какой знак нужно поставить, то не ты сочинил эту фразу, и, значит, это какой-то штамп, недоработка, недогляд. И это повод сказать как-то иначе, создать иной образ, завершить.

Знание - это не объект, не нужно превращать знание в объективность и форму правильности, незнание - это и есть колодец мысли для творчества(кажется, называется нигредо). Добиваясь же объективности формы общего знания, ты уплощаешь оболочку, а не наполняешь содержанием, окончательно выхолащивая тот образ, который мог бы создать.

Answer (score 0):

*Он приподнял голову и обнаружил, что лежит на грязной косе у спокойной мутной реки, окружённый группой аргониан с похожими узкими мордами и чешуёй всех цветов радуги, – **ярко-зелёной и пурпурной, голубой и оранжевой**, – красивой, как драгоценные камни.*

Однородный ряд обособлен двумя **тире**, как вставка. **Первая** запятая закрывает оборот, а **вторая** запятая ставится перед обособленным определением.

Comment: Любитель упрощать... Своеобразное увиливание от ответа. Не надо редактировать, если корректно. Даже нельзя. Какое закрытие оборота? Оно же относится к "цветов радуги".