# Почему нужно обособлять однородный ряд двумя тире?

Tags: запятые, тире, сложное-предложение

Оформление **двумя тире** предложено справочной службой:

*Да, в диких местах водились всякие мрачные твари **— тролли, химеры,** — порой встречались недружелюбно настроенные феи и блуждающие огоньки, но даже самые маленькие и глупые альтмеры знали, как избегать их.*

**Какому правилу** соответствует такое оформление?

Был вопрос по этой же теме, но о запятой:

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475399/Почему-стоит-запятая-перед-тире-Грамота-ру](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475399/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%83)

Comment: Это пояснительная конструкция. Она обособляется тире с двух сторон. В чем ваши сомнения?

Comment: Максим, спасибо за вопрос, но ответ не очень простой. Я добавлю материал в свой ответ.

Comment: Sharon, вас устраивает мой ответ? А то никак не отреагировали.

Answer (score 2):

**Ответ от**  **15 ноября 2023 года**

Оба примера решаем **методом блоков**. Этот метод предлагается в ПАС под ред. Лопатина  **[для сложных синтаксических конструкций.](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8/#id-11%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85)**  Там рассмотрены сложные предложения с несколькими **предикативными** основами,  а также **полупредикативные** обособленные  обороты.  **Оборот** может входить в блок или считаться отдельным блоком.

На стыке блоков ставятся знаки препинания, указывающие на **взаимоотношения блоков,** при сохранении **внутренних** знаков, поставленных на своем собственном синтаксическом основании.

**Пример 1**

*Да, в диких местах водились всякие мрачные твари — **тролли, химеры,** // порой встречались недружелюбно настроенные феи и блуждающие огоньки, /// **но даже самые маленькие и глупые альтмеры знали, как избегать их**.*

Здесь 4 **предикативные** основы, два блока. Граница проходит по союзу ***НО***, связь **сочинительная.**

**Первый блок**:  БСП, бессоюзная связь, присоединительный оборот в составе первого предложения.

**Второй блок:** СПП с придаточным изъяснительным.

**Пример 2**

*Он приподнял голову и обнаружил, что лежит на грязной косе у спокойной, мутной реки, окружённый группой аргониан с похожими узкими мордами и чешуёй всех цветов радуги: /// **ярко-зелёной и пурпурной, голубой и оранжевой — красивой, как драгоценные камни.***

Здесь **две предикативные** основы, причастный оборот и определительный оборот. **Два блока**, граница проходит перед определительным оборотом. Отношения **пояснительные**, обозначены двоеточием (можно обозначить единым знаком).

**Первый блок:** СПП с  придаточным изъяснительным, в его составе причастный оборот.

**Второй блок:** распространенный определительный оборот, в составе которого присоединительное определение, обособленное тире.

Comment: Sharon, хорошо, что добавили ссылку и пояснение о блоках. Давно хотел сказать, что пишете "методом блоков", а что это такое, не говорите. (Немного сомневаюсь в самом слове "метод", подходит ли оно здесь, ну это ладно...) У меня такой вопрос. Вы пишете: "обособленные обороты также могут **входить** в блоки", а во втором примере у вас оборот сам **является** блоком. Может, это стоит как-то уточнить, изменить. Может, тогда в начале лучше сказать о том, что, по вашему мнению, распространенный, обособл. опред. оборот (ну или типа того) можно считать самостоятельным блоком?

Comment: А, и ещё момент. В конце пишете: "...в составе которого присоединительное определение, обособленное тире". А перед "красивой" ставите также и запятую. Может, запятая там всё-таки не нужна?

Comment: Спасибо за замечания. Запятую, пожалуй, уберу; при двоеточии она там ни к чему.  Теперь о редактировании вступления. Может, написать так: В то же время полупредикативные конструкции (обособленные обороты) можно приравнять к предложениям, Оборот может входить в блок или считаться отдельным блоком.

Comment: Сейчас ещё раз прочитал ПАС. В принципе, думаю, да, оборот может являться блоком. Там так: "...или в которых **один** из блоков оказывается сложным предложением, на стыке блоков ставятся знаки препинания, указывающие на **взаимоотношения** блоков". Поэтому не надо писать "приравнять к предложениям". А вот "Оборот может входить в блок или считаться отдельным блоком" – хорошо.

Comment: Может, так: В то же время метод блоков применим и для полупредикативных конструкций (обособленных оборотов).  Оборот может входить в блок или считаться отдельным блоком. // И еще. Мне в примере (1) что-то запятая перед "порой" не нравится, убрать, что ли, ее? Пусть будет присоединение в конце первого предложения.

Comment: Если хотите так написать, то добавьте "считаю" / "по моему мнению", так как о полупредикативных там ни слова. Сошлитесь на цитату из ПАС, которую я привёл, в ней заложено много. // Запятую перед "порой" никак нельзя убрать, она же разделяет простые предлодения. Там **тире** спорное, потому что пояснение относится только к тварям и находится в конце предложения, и по правилам тире опускается. Но оно нужно, я уже писал об этом, в силу графики, чтобы понятно было где кончается предложение, так как там нет никакого союза, чтобы сразу понять, что начинается другое предложение.

Comment: Понятно. Ладно, пока оставлю, а завтра разберусь со вступлением. // Мне думается, что граница между предложениями понятна, на надо еще посмотреть. // Главное, со вступлением разобраться. Мне бы хотелось обойтись без своего мнения)

Comment: О, пока писал, вы не запятую убрали, а тире. Можно и так. Но ваши палочки хорошо показывают границу, а вот в нормальном тексте не очень:   *...водились всякие мрачные твари — тролли, химеры, порой встречались...*

Comment: Максим тоже пишет, что это присоединение, а тогда на границе между простыми предложениями в БСП будет стоять единый знак? Вроде бы достаточно запятой.  Там однородный ряд  ясно кончается.

Comment: Нет, он пишет, что пояснение. Это оно и есть. И да, запятой достаточно, но сразу переход чётко не читается, так как нет союза.

Comment: Ладно, оставлю так. Мы эту границу тоже блоками можем решать: ставим, что подходит. // Пояснение в виде присоединения, всё одно.  // Блоки тем и удобны: синтаксис выдумывать не надо)

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что обособление однородного ряда двумя тире удобно объяснить по правилам **для вставных конструкций.**

Запятая в этом случае **перенесенная**, она обозначает структуру предложения (бессоюзную сочинительную связь между первыми вторым предложением).

Похожее предложение было **в другом вопросе:**

*Он приподнял голову и обнаружил, что лежит на грязной косе у спокойной, мутной реки, окружённый группой аргониан с похожими узкими мордами и чешуёй всех цветов радуги (какой),  – **ярко-зелёной и пурпурной, голубой и оранжевой,** – красивой, как драгоценные камни.*

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475177/Нужна-ли-запятая-перед-тире-после-перечисления](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475177/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

**Но вот резюме:** Любитель упрощать... Своеобразное увиливание от ответа. Не надо редактировать, если корректно. Даже нельзя. Какое закрытие оборота? Оно же относится к "цветов радуги".

**Какой оборот?** Причастный, конечно (окруженный...). Но не поняли, не приняли :(

Или я ошибаюсь **с оборотом?**

Comment: Говорить можно все что угодно! Присоединяюсь к ответу!

Comment: Спасибо, Серж!.

Comment: А правда интересно, почему вы ставите запятую перед первым тире?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец, я с вами согласен. Я считаю, что запятая таки не нужна перед первым тире. Перед вторым запятая понятна. Но перед первым не должна стоять, т. к. эта пояснительная конструкция входит в причастный оборот с _окруженный_

Comment: Максим, не нужен, но необходим) Всю фразу просто невозможно понять без этой запятой. Но не будем уходить в сторону, речь-то не об этом, а о ДВУХ ТИРЕ в другом предложении. Почему мы делаем такой выбор?  Он вовсе НЕ ОДНОЗНАЧЕН: заканчивается одно предложение (а на его конце ОДНОРОДНЫЙ РЯД), а дальше бессоюзная связь.   (В том предложении была такая же ситуация, вот что интересно.) Что поставить: запятую, тире или запятую и тире? Есть правило? Я жду ответов.

Comment: Sharon, речь не об этом, а к чему тогда это "резюме"? И что сложного в понимании всем известных слов: "...чешуей всех цветов радуги – ярко-зелёной и пурпурной, голубой и оранжевой..."?

Comment: А к тому: ... окружённый группой аргониан с похожими узкими мордами и чешуёй всех цветов радуги – ярко-зелёной и пурпурной, голубой и оранжевой...  Все это будет прочитано в одну фонетическую фразу, то есть тире не будет обозначено более в сложной конструкции (долго объяснять, фонетика!). Но, кажется, вы забыли О ГЛАВНОМ. Тогда я предложила обособить ряд двумя тире, но меня "задвинули" довольно грубо. Дело не только в этой запятой, намного ВАЖНЕЕ  обособление ряда двумя тире.

Comment: Наличие тире уже не позволяет прочитать в одну фразу. О ГЛАВНОМ не видел, а сейчас там комментариев нет. Я с вами полностью согласен: второе тире никак нельзя не поставить, так как "красивой" прилепится к цветам и будет как бы однородный ряд, вообще не смотрящийся и нечитающийся.

Comment: Не будем обсуждать фонетику, это отдельная тема. Но метаморфозы тире можно посмотреть у Розенталя. Там есть интересные примеры в теме "Обособление приложений". Второе тире опускается (пункты 1 и 2). Прочитайте эти предложения с такой точки зрения: как "звучит" оставшееся тире. Мне кажется, что вообще без паузы. Но мало кто это слышит и понимает. Обычно копируют правило как оно есть и применяют бездумно.

Comment: Какое "оставшееся"? Оба тире "звучат", на то оно и тире, да и без пауз не прочитаешь такие большие фразы. // Об опускании я знаю, но это не тот случай. Так вы за второе тире или нет? Без него никак!

Comment: А то как же! Конечно, я за тире (даже за два тире). Красивое оформление. Но мне бы правило... Ведь был же альтернативный  вариант: только ЗАПЯТАЯ. (А вы уже переходите на восклицательные знаки? Вот и я говорю: не будем обсуждать фонетику.) И может, ответите мне про запятую в ТОМ предложении (из другого вопроса)? Закрывает или не закрывает оборот? Всем ж интересно, да и мне тоже.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь никаких вставных конструкций нет, только пояснительная.

---

> Да, в диких местах водились всякие мрачные твари — тролли, химеры, — порой встречались недружелюбно настроенные феи и блуждающие огоньки, но даже самые маленькие и глупые альтмеры знали, как избегать их.

---

***Тролли, химеры*** — это пояснительная конструкция. Она поясняет слова ***мрачные твари***. Как мы знаем, пояснительная конструкция всегда обособляется тире. Но как проверить, что это именно пояснение? Очень просто!

---

Между поясняемым словом и самим пояснением всегда можно поставить союз А ИМЕННО:

***Да, в диких местах водились всякие мрачные твари, а именно: тролли, химеры, — порой встречались...***

---

Также мы знаем, что поясняемое слово можно заменить самим пояснением, то есть знаем, что они **взаимозаменяемы**. А это так работает, т. к. пояснение — это и есть высказывание того же самого, но **другими словами**. То есть выходит:

*Да, в диких местах водились всякие **тролли, химеры**, порой...*

---

Вывод: тире поставлено ввиду того, что **тролли, химеры** — пояснительная конструкция.

Comment: @Sharon Вам помог ответ? Вы его не приняли и в комментариях не сказали почему.

Comment: Максим, да я теперь разве вспомню. Когда это было-то! Может. не видела. Посмотрю позже, ага?

Answer (score 0):

Рассмотрим предложение из другого вопроса.

Это предложение **без вставки**:

*Он приподнял голову и обнаружил, что лежит на грязной косе у спокойной, мутной реки, окружённый группой аргониан с похожими узкими мордами и чешуёй всех цветов радуги **(,)** **красивой, как драгоценные камни.***

К нему добавлена вставка. **Выделенная запятая** закрывает причастный **оборот**, по правилам она должна сохраниться. Но эта же запятая обозначает **структуру** исходного предложения и ставится после ряда. **Это так**?

Помогите, совы!

Вот **мой вариант** (два тире, две запятые):

*Он приподнял голову и обнаружил, что лежит на грязной косе у спокойной, мутной реки, окружённый группой аргониан с похожими узкими мордами и чешуёй всех цветов радуги, **– ярко-зелёной и пурпурной, голубой и оранжевой**, – красивой, как драгоценные камни.*

Кто против, напишите, пожалуйста, **В ЧЕМ МОЯ ОШИБКА.**
Какое правило Розенталя нарушено? (Несколько человек были против.) Я могу ошибиться, но пока не понимаю в чем.

Comment: А почему вы с Леопольдом называете участников совами? Интересно просто узнать :)